# How to retrieve Image from Firebase database using recyclerview

Tags: android

```
   holder.txcom.setText("Comments: "+wtm.getWorkcom());
       Picasso.get().load(wtm.getImageurl()).into(holder.imgwaste);
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+wtm.getImageurl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is my code to retrieve image from firebase. I used Glide and Picasso but not showing the image. In Toast image link can show stored on firebase database. But not show the Image.

Comment: are the comments retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

1) add Context to yourAdapter constuctor:

```
public yourAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
       }
```

2) and try this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(yourUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: not working. Your answer is to change the dependency v of Picasso high to low.